# how to fix the autocomplete overlay defect?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

> Here i placed sample code related to defect,
>   I used **appendTo="body"** in p-autoComplete tag because of these i had a defect, If you click the drop-down and scroll the mouse over screen, you can find it, Please suggest me how to fix these defect using CSS
>   [click here to view defect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgUxl.jpg)

## app.component.html

```
    <div class="ui-g-12">

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4 ui-lg-4 filter-wrapper dropshadow addBorder"

      style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px" >

      <div class="clearSearchButton" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef">

        <h2 class="search-title pad-left10">Search</h2>

        <button pButton class="clearSearch pull-right mar-top10 mar-right8 ui-button-tertiary" (click)="clearSearch()">

          Clear Search

        </button>

      </div>

      <p-scrollPanel [style]="{ height: 'calc(100vh - 291px)', overflow: 'visible !important' }" styleClass="custom"

        class="customSearchScroll" #searchScrollPanel>

<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<div class="ui-g-12">

    <p-autoComplete appendTo="body" #b2bdoctype [forceSelection]="true" formControlName="b2bDocType" placeholder="B2B-Doc-Type"

      emptyMessage="No Result Found" [suggestions]="filteredBrands"

      (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [(ngModel)]="brand" [style]="{'width':'100%', 'word-break': 'break-word'}"

      [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" [dropdown]="true" [minLength]="1">

    </p-autoComplete>


</div>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>

<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>
<p>
    Bioinspired, biomimetic and nanobiomaterials are emerging as the most promising area of research within the area of biological materials science and engineering. The technological significance of this area is immense for applications as diverse as tissue engineering and drug delivery biosystems to biomimicked sensors and optical devices. Bioinspired, Biomimetic and Nanobiomaterials provides a unique scholarly forum for discussion and reporting of structure sensitive functional properties of nature inspired materials.
</p>



      </p-scrollPanel>

      <div appShortcut class="ui-g-12 pad0 filter-footer">

        <div class="ui-g-11 favoritesFooter pad-right7">

          <button pButton appShortcut="ctrl+alt+1" label="Search" class="mar-top5" (click)="search(1)"></button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

```
app.component.ts
=================
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   brands: string[] = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Honda', 'Jaguar', 'Mercedes', 'Renault', 'Volvo', 'VW'];
  filteredBrands: any[];  brand: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  filterBrands(event) {
    this.filteredBrands = [];
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < this.brands.length; i++) {
        const brand = this.brands[i];
        if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
            this.filteredBrands.push(brand);
        }
    }
}

}
```

```
app.component.scss
===================

// @import '~ngx-prime-theme/theme/_typography.scss';

// @import '~ngx-prime-theme/theme/_colors.scss';



@keyframes ui-progress-spinner-color {

  100%,

  0% {

      stroke: #d62d20;

  }

  40% {

      stroke: #0057e7;

  }

  66% {

      stroke: #008744;

  }

  80%,

  90% {

      stroke: #ffa700;

  }

}

.cal {

  z-index: 5;

  position: absolute;

  width: 70%;



  background-color: white;

}

.right {

  right: 6%;

}

.left{

  left: 1%;

}

.filter-wrapper {

  border-radius: 6px;

  border-style: solid;

  border-color: #efefef;

  background: white;

  height: 100%;

  padding-top: 5px;



  .filter-form {

    height: 100%;

  }



  .search-title {

    // @include getTypographyStyles('h2');

    display: inline-block;

    font-size: 20px;

  }



  .clearSearchButton {

    padding-right: 10px;

  }



  .fav-back-color {

    background-color: blue($color: #000000);;

  }



  .filter-footer {

    padding: 10px;

    float: right;

    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;

  }



  .text-gray {

    color: #efefef;

  }

}

.gridCss {

  border-radius: 6px;

  border-style: solid;

  border-color: #efefef;

  background: white;

  margin-top: 0px;

}

.addBorder {

  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;

}

.clearSearch {


  cursor: pointer;

}

.customSearchScroll {

  .ui-scrollpanel-content {

    height: calc(100% + 18px);

    width: calc(100% + 118px);

    padding: 1em 0;

    position: relative;

    overflow: auto;

    box-sizing: border-box;

  }

  &,

  &:hover {

    .ui-scrollpanel-bar-y {

      margin-left: -1px;

      width: 7px !important;

    }

  }

}

// .searchScrollPanel /deep/ .ui-scrollpanel-bar-x {

//   display: none !important;

//   float: right;

// }

.filter-footer {

  padding: 10px;

  float: right;

  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;

}

.favoritesFooter {

  text-align: right;

  margin-left: 0;

  width: 100%;

}

:host ::ng-deep input {

  width: 100%;

}

::ng-deep .ui-calendar.ui-calendar-w-btn .ui-inputtext {

  font-size: 14px;

  width: 100% !important;

}

:host ::ng-deep #b2 .ui-button:not(.ui-button-icon-only) {

  min-width: 0px;

}

.borderCurve {

  padding: 0px;

  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;

  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px

}

// .main-content /deep/ .ui-table-scrollable-body {

//   height: calc(100vh - 317px);

// }

.classh3 {

  font-family: "Proxima Nova SEMIBOLD", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;

  font-size: 1.125rem;

  line-height: 1.375rem;

  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;

  text-transform: none;

  margin: 0;

}

.messageErr {

  font-family: "Proxima Nova SEMIBOLD", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;

  font-size: 1.25rem;

  line-height: 1.5rem;

  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;

  text-transform: none;

  height: calc(100vh - 292px);

  color: #939393;

}

.messageErr, .message-wrapper {

  font-size: 50px;

}

.calBorder {

  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  border-radius: 7px;

  margin-top: 2px;

}

 .display-middle {

    position: relative;

    text-align: center;

    display: block;

    top: 35%;

    padding: 10px;

    line-height: 40px;

  }

  .searchWidth {

    width: 254px; 

    margin-top: -6px;

  }

  .iconsHolder {

    position: relative;

    bottom: 2px;

  }

  .buttonStyle {

    background: transparent;

    padding: 5px;

    border: none;

    outline: none;

    cursor: pointer;

    display: inline-block;

    font-size: 16px;

    height: 44px;

    color: gray;

    margin-top: -5px;

  }

  .filterColor {

    color: blue;

    outline: none;

    cursor: pointer;

  }

  ::ng-deep .custom-accordion .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {

    background-color: white;

    border-bottom: solid 1px #efefef;

    padding: 0px;

  }

 ::ng-deep .custom-accordion .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header:hover {

    background-color: white;

  }

 ::ng-deep .custom-accordion-segment .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a {

    padding-left:15px;

    .ui-accordion-toggle-icon {

      position: absolute;

      right: 9px;

      color: #007dba;

    }

  }

  ::ng-deep p-calendar {

    .ui-datepicker {

    top: 36px !important;

    width: 275px;

    }

    }

    ::ng-deep .ui-timepicker {

      text-align: center;

      padding: 0; 

  }

  #cursorPointer {

    cursor: pointer;

  }

  #cursorPointer:hover {

    color: #007dba;

  }

//   .no-border {

//     /deep/ .ui-accordion-header{

//       border-bottom: none !important;

//     }

//   }

  .autocompleteFilter {

    ::ng-deep .ui-accordion-content.ui-widget-content  {

      padding: 0px 15px 20px;

    }

  }

  ::ng-deep p-accordion .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-wrapper:not(.ui-accordion-content-wrapper-overflown) {

    box-shadow: none;

}

.filter-title {

  color: #939393;

  font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 55 ROMAN", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;

  font-size: 0.75rem;

  line-height: 1rem;

  letter-spacing: 0.01rem;

}

.noRecordDisplay{

  height: calc(100vh - 317px);

 background: white;

 color: #939393; font-family: "Proxima Nova SEMIBOLD", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;

 letter-spacing: 0.01rem;

}

.minimum-column-width {

  box-sizing: border-box;

//   @include getTypographyStyles('h6');

  white-space: nowrap;

  overflow: hidden !important;

  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  padding-bottom: 5px !important;



}

.headerHeight {

  padding-top: 5px;

  height: 35px;

}

:host ::ng-deep p-paginator .ui-paginator {

  text-align: left;

  margin: 1px;

  padding: 0.5em;

  height: 29px;

}

::ng-deep p-paginator .ui-paginator .ui-paginator-element .ui-paginator-icon.pi-caret-left:before {

  margin-left: 15px;

}

::ng-deep .pi-step-backward:before {

  margin-left: 15px;

}

.td {

  font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT Pro 55 ROMAN", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;

    font-size: 0.625rem;

    line-height: 0.875rem;

    letter-spacing: 0rem;

    text-transform: none;

    color: #444444;

    padding-top: 6px;

    padding-bottom: 6px;

}

::ng-deep .tooltip .ui-tooltip-text {

  width: 100%; 

  word-wrap: break-word;

  white-space: initial;

}

::ng-deep p-dropdown .ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label.ui-placeholder {

  width: 100%;

}
```